# Why does my smartphone show as USB or external drive on my PC?

Tags: external-hard-drive, smartphone

Normally, when a smartphone is connected to a computer, it is seen or recognized by the PC as external drive. Why is this the case? What can I read to find out the reason behind this?

Comment: Because it reports itself as a storage device.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/192732/android-usb-connections-explained-mtp-ptp-and-usb-mass-storage/ worth a read

Answer (score 1):

The exact mechanisms depends, but the simple answer is "its the easiest way to expose storage to a PC without additional drivers". In the bad old days, between the simple, bulletproof 'dumb phones' of the past, and modern smart phones, you'd have 'half witted' phones that needed additional drivers and software unique to the phone to do *anything*. I do believe iPhones need itunes to do anything on it - but I'll leave it to the reader to decide if an iPhone is truely smart or not.

Its worth considering outside Cynogen mod, most modern phones arn't mounted as 'hard drives' or 'removable media'. They were *once* so you could do neat things like boot your PC off a phone, but its problematic. Instead, phones use MTP (which has been used for other devices), which essentially abstracts the storage on the phone so you don't have direct access. Basically your phone tells your PC "I have these files" and your PC tells your phone what operations to do.

Some phones also expose a 'read only' partitions with drivers - especially chinese makes.

So the reasons? Well, it makes it fast and easy to copy media on and off your phone. The mechanism? Typically MTP, tho you can fall back to PTP.